# How do I quit a Django development server with a bash script?

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, shell

I wrote a bash script to start a Django development sever, however, I want to be able to quit the server while it's running with a bash script as well. I'm writing a web app for Koding.com that starts a Django process in an online terminal linked to the user's personal VM by running a bash script with a press of a button, and I want users to be able to end the process with a press of a button as well. I know that control C would end the process, but I haven't been able to find out how to do that in a bash script. How could I go about doing this? Thanks!
[image]

UPDATE: I ultimately combined my selected answer for this question and this answer from another question I asked (how to run unix commands in django shell) to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22777849/2181017

Comment: Old school: you can kill the process using its PID. Write the PID into a `server.pid` file on startup, and then `kill` it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can kill the process listening on 8000/TCP:

```
fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

The `fuser` command shows which processes are using the named files, sockets, or filesystems and the `-k` option kills them as well.

> Wait, just to clarify, there's no way to temporarily exit that django shell thing so that I could run a unix command?

When you start the development server it will run in foreground, blocking the prompt. You can pause the task that is running in foreground by hitting `CTRL+Z`, and then send the task to background running the `bg` command (I assume you are running the bash shell or a lookalike). The `jobs` command will list paused tasks or tasks running in background. You can bring a task to foreground using the `fg` command.

Please refer to the bash man page (`man bash`).

Comment: Thanks! Would you also happen to know I can run that command where that cursor is in the picture? I can't seem to run and unix commands from there. (I have no knowledge of how Django works)

Comment: I guess you can just hit CTRL+C to terminate the process if you are using a terminal. The `fuser` command can run from another terminal or  be called from other process as long as the terminal or process are running on the same server.

Comment: That I know, however, I wish to have users be able to press the "Stop Django" button to terminate the process, as this installer is meant to be super easy for people to use. Thus, when a user presses the button, I will run a shell script that would ideally end the process. What you provided does indeed terminate the process, but I was wondering if you know how I could run that command without opening another terminal, since anything I type at where the cursor is, in the picture, doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: No problem, you can run the `fuser` command from other process as long as it runs on the same server and the user has enough privileges to kill the process (usually the same user running django or root). What programming language are you using to provide that UI?

Comment: Haha, um, my question now is more of how I can run unix commands at the point of where my cursor is, in that picture above. Typing "fuser -k 8000/tcp" then pressing enter there doesn't seem to do anything, since it's in some django shell or something. Would you happen to know how I could run unix commands there? Thanks again.

Comment: You can't, unless you run the Django test server on the background by appending a `&` to the line containing the `manage.py` command.

Comment: Wait, just to clarify, there's no way to temporarily exit that django shell thing so that I could run a unix command?

Answer (score 1):

what about GNU screen? http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

```
screen
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
ctrl + a then d (this will detach from screen)
exit (from the shell)
```

when you need to stop, login back in the shell

```
screen -r
ctrl + c
exit (from screen)
exit (from the shell)
```

put this in `~/.screenrc` for a nice screen statusline

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `CTRL+C` to quit your server .
else with ubuntu system you can do like below .

```
prashant@prashant-OptiPlex-3010:~$  ps -eaf|grep runserver
prashant  3445  2805  4 11:20 pts/0    00:00:00 python manage.py runserver
prashant  3446  3445  5 11:20 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python manage.py runserver
prashant  3449  3375  0 11:20 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto runserver
prashant@prashant-OptiPlex-3010:~$ kill 3446
prashant@prashant-OptiPlex-3010:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `.bat` script in Command Prompt in Windows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A port=8000
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -ano ^| findstr :%port%') DO (
    SET /A processid=%%T
    TASKKILL /PID %%T /F
)
```

This will kill all connections using `port 8000` (you may started more than one instance of the server running simultaneously`.

`SUCCESS: The process with PID 5104 has been terminated.`