# How do I use unix commands while a Django development server is running? (picture provided)

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, unix

I was wondering if I could run unix commands without quitting the server. If so, how? I used a Bash script to start the server, and I want to have a Bash script that quits the server to run when users presses the stop button. However, when the Bash script is run, the commands don't seem to be executed, but just hangs there.

[image]

[image]

I tried running `fuser -k 8000/tcp`, but this clearly isn't how I am supposed to be doing this, as it did not run. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: you want to run "fuser -k 8000/tcp" while development server is running ?

Comment: @Priyank Patel Right. I want to quit the server with a bash script which runs "fuser -k 8000/tcp", instead of using control-c.

Comment: How about `import os` and then `os.kill(8000, 2)` ?

Comment: I'd recommend you use a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux. Run the server in one of the terminals and your shell to do your work in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the development server in the background as

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

and the messages and logs are written in the file nohup.out.

And you can perform any unix commands after the nohup operation at your will. Regarding, the bash script to kill the development server, you can find the `pid` of the development server and kill it using `kill` command.